# rich:popupPanel with <a4j:status> is not working in JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

When i hit on Submit button rich popup panel is not working.Should it be outside the h:form or inside . I tried both ways but it is not working. Please help me where i am going wrong .Below is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/pages/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="heading">
            <h:outputText value="Paging” </h:outputText>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:panelGrid id="panel2">
    <h:form id="my_form">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <h:panelGroup id="globalmessages">
            <h:message id="key1" for="key" style="color:red" showDetail="true" />
            <h:message id="lock1" for="lock" errorStyle ="color:red" showDetail="true" />
         </h:panelGroup>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table  width="700px" >
        <tr>
            <td align="right" width="30%"><label>Files: </label></td>
            <td align="left" width="70%"><h:outputText value= "Hosting file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" width="30%"><label for="lastdate">
            Last Date:</label></td>
            <td align="left" width="70%"><h:panelGrid id="panel1">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <rich:calendar id=" lastdate "
                        value="#{myBean.ladate}"
                        locale="Locale.US" popup="true" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                        showApplyButton="false" todayControlMode = "hidden" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="220px"
                        enableManualInput = "true" converterMessage = "Entered wrong date format"
                        style="width:200px" required="true" requiredMessage="Last date: is required."/>
                (MM/DD/YYYY)
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value ="getHost" action="#{mybean.hosted}" id="key" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" width="30%"><label>Data: </label></td>
            <td align="left" width="70%"><h:inputText id="datarelated" value="#{myBean.dataExist}" style="padding-bottom: 68px; width: 165px;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
            <a4j:commandButton  value ="SubmitVal" action="#{myBean.onVal}" id="lock" style="height: 25px; width: 90px;"  
            render="globalmessages" status="ajaxStatus"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </h:form>
    <a4j:status name="ajaxStatus"                                           
        onstart="#{rich:component('waitPanel')}.show('',{top:'340px', left:'450px',height:'50px', width:'350px'})"
        onstop="#{rich:component('waitPanel')}.hide()" >
    </a4j:status>
                            <rich:popupPanel  id="waitPanel" style="text-align:center">
                            <h:form id="test">
                                <h:outputText value="Please wait...Calculating" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:large" />
                            </h:form>
                            </rich:popupPanel> 
     </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "Not working" is not enough information to go by, what do you expect it to do and what does it actually do? Also, when posting code, show only the relevant parts, if the calendar is not part of the problem then don't show it.

Comment: When i click on the submit it goes to mybean onVal methid and there it inserts some records int DB.SO mean while when it is inserting i want the user to show up waiting message . But i dont see any popup with waiting message.

Comment: You can make the panel show from JS console (`RichFaces.component('fullPanelId').show(..)`) to see what's happening, have you checked if the panel isn't outside of the screen?

Comment: Sorry Makhiel i did not get you . Can you please elaborate on "have you checked if the panel isn't outside of the screen". What changes should i make in my code and check.

Comment: The panel can be positioned outside the visible screen or hidden behind another element. Check the generated code in your browser and find the panel, the popup itself is a div with class `rf-pp-cntr`.